# TinyMCE modal in JQuery modal not editable

Tags: jquery, tinymce, modal-dialog

I am running a tinyMCE editor inside a JQuery UI modal dialog. Everything works fine, except for those functions of tinyMCE which themselves open a new modal (links, for example). These modals are displayed fine but the input areas are not editable.
The js code is OK according to Firebug and the HTML is pretty straightforward.

Any clue where it might come from?

Edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: "autolink link table textcolor",
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | forecolor backcolor | bold italic | link unlink | table"
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sendmail")
        .button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-mail-closed"
            },
            text: false
        })
        .click(function(){
            $("#sendmailform").dialog("open");
        })
    ;
    $(function(){
        $("#sendmailform")
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: "Send mail confirmation",
                modal:true,
                width: 750,
                [buttons & ajax]
            })
        ;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Harry, the great guys on the TinyMCE bugtracker provided the solution.

I just added the code below on top of my script loaded after the DOM, just before loading tinyMCE:

```
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
    if ($(event.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

Works like a charm, while the one posted by @Harry did not.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5917

For jQuery UI dialogs you can do this:

```
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    _allowInteraction: function(event) {
        return !!$(event.target).closest(".mce-container").length || this._super( event );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for providing the link. Upvoted, but not the solution - posted it in the answers below :)

Comment: After quite some developments, it appears that both solutions work depending on context. The one I posted worked on most pages, but on one of them kept throwing an "event is not defined error". I replaced my code with the one above, which worked.

Comment: this works when you have nested dialogues on the page. why isn't this built into tinymce by default?!

Comment: I'm using the react version of tinyMCE, do you have a solution that works with react? I'm not suing JQUERY and the modal where this happens is react-bootstrap/Modal

Answer (score 0):

Your question need more detail to answered, but you can try this:

```
tinymce.get('editor_id').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
```

Comment: How would that fix the OP's problem?