# TinyMCE dropdown not working in GWT Popup

Tags: gwt, popup, tinymce

I have encountered a problem, that the TinyMCE editor it's not working inside a GWT popup panel.

After some research I found similar problems with JQuery and BootStrap modal dialogs (see: [TinyMCE modal in JQuery modal not editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271634/tinymce-modal-in-jquery-modal-not-editable)).

Does anyone have any solution that works also in GWT?

Thank you!

Comment: It would be very useful if you put testable code in your question or link to source and working example. In other case you are waiting for someone who had the same problem in past but that means you have strong faith

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? How is it not working?

Comment: The only problem is with the dropdowns in the toolbar. Everything works except the dropdowns, which are not opening properly nor are they clickable